# Odoo - How can I bind a window action to a first level menu in the sidebar?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to associate a window action to a menu placed in the left sidebar of Odoo interface. I have a menu named Academy in the top menu bar, and another menu named "Academy Content" in the left sidebar. Here is an image of the interface.

Link to image: [Menus Odoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl1bf.png)

The "Academy Content" menu doesn't have children. I want to associate a window action (named action_academy_teachers) to the "Academy Content" menu.
In the view (view.xml file), I'm defining two menus.

```xml
<menuitem sequence="0" id="menu_academy" name="Academy"/>
<menuitem id="menu_academy_content" parent="menu_academy" name="Academy Content" action="action_academy_teachers"/>
```

The problem is that I can't click on the "Academy Content" menu, it's only a static text, not a link.
But if I add a child menu (named "Academy Teachers") to the "Academy Content" menu, and I associate the window action "action_academy_teachers" to "Academy Teachers" menu, this window action is triggered when I click in this menu.

```xml
<menuitem sequence="0" id="menu_academy" name="Academy"/>
<menuitem id="menu_academy_content" parent="menu_academy"
          name="Academy Content"/>
<menuitem id="menu_academy_content_teachers"
          parent="menu_academy_content"
          action="action_academy_teachers" name="Academy Teachers"/>
```

**But I want to the "action_academy_teachers" action is triggered when I click on the "Academy Content" menu. I don't want to create another child menu to do this.**

window action code:

```xml
<record id="action_academy_teachers" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Academy teachers</field>
  <field name="res_model">academy.teachers</field>
</record>
```

**Additional information**:
Odoo: version 8
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Normaly it's not working by default, because of the architecture of menus and their structure.

So you need to modify how the menus are displayed, by overriding the "web.menu_secondary" template in "web" module, to add a link to your action.

To achieve that, just add this section to your XML file (or create a new module that depends on 'web' module) :

```
<template id="menu_secondary" inherit_id="web.menu_secondary">
        <div class="oe_secondary_menu_section" position="replace">
            <div class="oe_secondary_menu_section">
                <span t-if="not menu['action']">
                    <t t-raw="menu['name']"/>
                </span>
                <span t-if="menu['action']">
                    <t t-call="web.menu_link"/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

Hope this can help!